# Why is this question getting so many views?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, moderators, voting

[Where is the calmest place on Earth?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13446/where-is-the-calmest-place-on-earth)

This question is getting more attention than any other question I have asked before. What did I do right? To me it is just another question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably went on the Hot network questions list. The criteria for appearing on that list are explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page/61343#61343). What that means is that people who are not users of ESSE are looking at it thus ensuring many views than just registered users on this site.

Comment: FYI, you can find the formula that create the HNQ list [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page/61343#61343).

Comment: @plannapus please feel free to edit my answer as you wish

Comment: @plannapus I edited it in as suggested :-)