# Why does an older revision of my question get more views?

Tags: discussion, support, policy, asking-questions

[Where is the calmest place on Earth?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13446/where-is-the-calmest-place-on-earth)

The above question was on fire getting many views.
The person who edited my question did it good taste but, the views drastically stopped. IMO that is a negative edit even if may read better.

Why did the later edit make such a difference in view count?
Am I allowed to keep it on the revision I deemed best even if a Moderator edits it?

Related: [Why is this question getting so many views?](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/why-is-this-question-getting-so-many-views)

Comment: The view count dropped because it fell off the hot network questions. I doubt it had anything to do with the edit.

Comment: @bon are you sure? because the moderators said it was pulling non SE users now it is not.